# UIView: insert subview above multiple views issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, ios6

Actually i have multiple tableview and i want to add temporaryView above both of these table views.

This thing is not working for me.

I have also applied this thing:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:_viewTempRight];
```

Comment: Are all subviews placed on the controller's view ?

Comment: yes all subviews are added to self.view.

Comment: Please show some code on how you add the views and reference them. Is _viewTempRight actually a valid pointer?

Comment: First of all i have two tableViews ok...then i am adding tempView like this.if(!_viewTemp)
    {
        _viewTemp = [[UIView alloc]init];
        _viewTemp.frame = CGRectMake(0, 109, 40 , self.view.bounds.size.height-offsetY-BottomView_HEIGHT);
        
     
        _viewTemp.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hiddenImage.png"] ]; //add background image
        

        [self.view insertSubview:_viewTemp aboveSubview:self._tableView];// this is first table view
        
    }

Answer (score 0):

bringSubviewToFront always work, if you use this in this manner :

```
[parentView bringSubviewToFront:childView];
```

if then also doesn't work try removing the view which you want on top and then add again as subview